# Python: send arguments to function in dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

Is it possible to pass arguments to a function within a dictionary?

```
d = {"A": foo(), "B": bar()}

def foo(arg):
    return arg + 1

def bar(arg):
    return arg - 1
```

In this case I want to pass **arg** to **bar()** by referencing the function dynamically

```
d["B"]  #<-- pass arg to bar()
```

Comment: Your dictionary syntax is wrong. The parens shouldn't be there. Otherwise you're actually calling the functions immediately and storing their return values.

Comment: @Doorknob - I wouldn't really call that a problem with syntax. It's perfectly valid Python; it just won't give the right result (and functions have to be defined before they're referenced and called, of course).

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler - The `foo` I'm looking at in the question doesn't do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible, but you have to refer to the function (e.g. `foo`) without already calling it (e.g. `foo()`).

```
def foo(arg):
    return arg + 1

def bar(arg):
    return arg - 1

d = {"A": foo, "B": bar}
```

Result:

```
>>> d['A'](5)
6
```

Comment: You should add that `foo` references the function named `foo`, whereas `foo()` (with parens) calls it.

Comment: I thought that was pretty clear since it was the only change in the code (other than eliminating the `NameError`), but hopefully the edit improves it.